# How to insert/update a row in MySQL for JSON column using Java SprinBoot CrudRepository

Tags: mysql, json, spring-boot

I am trying to insert a row in MySQL JSON column using Java SpringBoot CrudRepository. I already skimmed through multiple posts but couldn't get answer for this.

I defined a custom query as:

```html
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "insert into cs_test_json(config) values (':data')", nativeQuery = true)
 public void setData(@Param("data") String string);
```

and MySQL table(cs_test_json) is :

```html
id int
config JSON
```

In my Controller I wrote

```html
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
  data.put("name", "kc");
  data.put("age", 28);
  data.put("city", "Abad");

  repository.setData(data.toString());
```

When I run this application I always get (on calling setData method)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 0 in value for column 'cs_test_json.config'

Please suggest me what I am missing.
I am using MySQL 8

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spotted the `':data'`. Can you give a try with `:data`.? It's a string that you pass and it doesn't need a quotation to further qualify. Spring data takes care of it.

I'm replying from a mobile. Kindly excuse typos and formatting.